# Twitter Bootstrap 3: Input Add-On with Validation Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've run into an interesting issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3 .. seems like there's a formatting issue when doing validation on input add-on's within a form.  The add-on get's shifted in sizing and in the case of a button just shifted. Direct from the twitter bootstrap page

```
    <div class="input-group has-success">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Looks like the following

[image: Screen Shot of Issue]

Here's a JSFiddle to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/HdxT3/

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for all the CSS modifications. Bootstrap allows you to do this natively:

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
    <div class="input-group">    
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP does not use CSS.. they purely uses classes in their Fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the CSS hacks in the other answers. I'm telling OP that he doesn't need those because he can do it purely in Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm adding a comment to my answer but I'll leave it in case it helps others. This is the better solution.

Comment: Is it just me, or this no longer works. It only styles the inputbox, but not the button.

Comment: Trying it in the jsfiddle that OP used it does seem like it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure a little bit, and added some `css`

**Mark-up**

```
  <div class="input-group has-success">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success
        <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"/> 
       <button class="btn btn-default" id="style" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>     
        </label>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#style{

    margin-left: -4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-left: none;
}
```

Sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdxT3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.control-label{
    display: table-caption;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HdxT3/3/

Comment: You should use Leo Jweda's answer instead, it is the proper way to do it using the standard Bootstrap controls.